# How to change from quadratic to linear equation

Tags: curves

Equation of curve

> $ y = 4x^2 -2 $.

The following equation is obtained when this curve equation is expressed in linear form

> $Y =-2X+4 $.

How do we change the curve equation to the linear equation? I tried the following

> $ y = 4x^2 -2$
>
> $y + 2 = 4x^2$
>
> $y + 2 = 4(x)^2$
>
> $y + 2 = 4(x-0)^2$
>
> $y = 4(x-0)^2 - 2$

I need to express $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Comment: You can't magically turn a quadratic into a line...

Comment: Hint: Start by setting $X=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=4x^2-2 \\ y+6=4x^2+4$$
Compare with $Y=-2X+4$, this implies, $Y=y+6$, $X=-2x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such *unique* change of variables to convert between the two, at least not without additional constraints. For example $\;X=f(x,y),\, Y=y-4x^2-2f(x,y)+6\;$ means that $\,Y=-2X+4 \iff y=4x^2-2\,$ holds for any arbitrary function $\,f(x,y)\,$.